# Determining whether a string is a file name in c#

Tags: c#, file

What is a way to determine whether a given string is a file name or not in c#?

Comment: what do you mean, is a filename? i see no way of reliably predicting something like that. if you mean "could be and has some file extension" then say so :)

Comment: Do you mean whether or not a string is a *valid* file name, or whether or not a string matches the name of an existing file?

Comment: Yes, I wanted to check whether a string can be a valid file name, if there is such a thing. Not whether the file is found on my system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to check if it's a valid filename, you can try checking for disallowed characters

```
bool IsValidFilename(string testName)
{
 Regex containsABadCharacter = new Regex("[" + Regex.Escape(System.IO.Path.InvalidPathChars) + "]");
 if (containsABadCharacter.IsMatch(testName) { return false; };

 return true;
}
```

I think this is suitable, because filenames can be quite exotic and still be valid filenames.

Answer (score 2):

if you mean does the given string exists as a filename then here you go:

```
var file = "myfile.txt";
var fileExists = System.IO.File.Exists(file);
```

If you mean does this string conform to windows standard filename naming conventions then:

```
var file = "mybadfile<\\/.txt";
var invalidFileChars = System.IO.Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars();
var isInvalidFilename = invalidFileChars.Any(s => file.Contains(s));
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `System.IO.File.Exists(givenStr)`, depending on what you mean.

If you want to know if `givenStr` has no illegal characters, maybe use `!System.IO.Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars().Intersect(givenStr).Any()` (just because everyone else includes this in their answer).

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be to test if the string corresponds to an actual file name using `System.IO.File.Exists(...)`.

Filenames do not follow a prescribed pattern. `Document.doc` would be a valid filename, but so would `asdfasdfasdf234234` and `树`.

Answer (score 1):

The only way a string could **not** be a valid filename is if it included one of the characters in `Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()`.  As long as it doesn't have any of those illegal characters it is a legal file name.

If your curious if there is an actual file at that location then you can use `File.Exists`.